# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO): even from command line

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp, localhost

I searched the solution, but i didn't find it at all!!

I installed Xampp two years ago, and it worked fine up to yesterday.
I used to manage MySql at "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/", but now it shows me this error:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

if i try to manage mysql users from command line, shell or ssh, i always get the same error!
this is my config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma_savedsearches';
```

... and this is my.ini

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
```

Every help would be appreciated...

Comment: what does mysql_error.log say. Also on a side note, using no password on your **root** mysql user is a bad idea, even on a home dev machine.

Comment: Try following command from command prompt "mysql -uroot -p" now pass root password as input and share results.

Comment: hi Zafar Malik. I tryed the command "mysql -uroot -p",  and typed "root" as password. The result is: ERROR1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). I get the same error if i digit no password, as specified in my.ini and config.inc.php files.

Answer (score 1):

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

1. open my.ini file located at C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql[version]\my.ini
2. change password field

from this->

`#password  = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock`

to this->

`password   = password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock`

3. now goto `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin[version]` find `config.inc.php` and change

this line -> `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`

to this -> `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

and

this lines ->`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';`

```
          $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`
```

to this ->    `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';`

```
          $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';`
```

4. restart all services of wamp server
5. now type localhost in your browser wamp start page should appear
6. click on phpmyadmin it will open up a login page for MySQL, login using your

username=`user`

and

password=`password`

6. this should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I lost the "root" password, so I didn't have administrator privileges. I solved it following [this](http://www.jovicailic.org/2012/04/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password-under-windows/)

guide, updating the password. After restarting the pc, it worked...
Hope this could help...